# I have to retrieve a value from sql server 2008 database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i have created my database as follows :

`userid, password, type`

Now in my `login.aspx.cs` I want to code such that if `userid` and password are matching and a user belongs to the type U then it will go to `userpage` and if type is A then go to admin page. The code is shown here but how to send it to the type. I am having confusion of how to retrieve and compare and then redirect it to the following page.

```
public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = TextBox1.Text;
        string pass = TextBox2.Text;
        string  utp;
        string  connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newdb"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        string qry = "select * from login where uid=@username and pass=@pass";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry,con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass",pass);

        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ad.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            Response.Redirect("http://localhost:55575/WebSite13/admin/Adminpage.aspx");
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The type column will be in the `DataTable dt` (should be the  first and only row); `dt.Rows[0]["type"].ToString()` will give you the value.  However, I'd recommand using a `SqlDataReader` for this rather than creating a whole `DataTable`.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You just need to work this this a bit:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    Response.Redirect("http://localhost:55575/WebSite13/admin/Adminpage.aspx");
```

That code says that if there are any rows in the database that matched my query, which was a user with the specified user name and password, then redirect. However, that's not really what you want to do is it? You'd like to check that type. So let's modify that a bit:

```
bool hasRows = dt.Rows.Count > 0;
string type = hasRows ? string.Empty : dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("type");

if (hasRows && type == "A")
    Response.Redirect("http://localhost:55575/WebSite13/admin/Adminpage.aspx");
else if (hasRows && type == "U")
    Response.Redirect("http://localhost:55575/WebSite13/admin/userpage.aspx");
```

Comment: @Vulcronos, absolutely! Great catch my friend.

Comment: @neoistheone .. i didn't understand the second line of your code... which has the ternary operator.

Comment: thanks @Vulcronos your solution worked... i have a cofusion when we are doing dt.Rows[0] it should stay on first row  only how it is going on next all rows

Comment: @user2334012 Not sure what you mean.  Rows[0] will only be the first row.  If you need more then one row, you have a problem in that the same username/password are in your database twice.

Comment: @Vulcronos no its not the problem. Because i have taken the userid as primary key so they cant be any duplicate entries. I was just asking how to this program will go to each and every row.

Answer (score 1):

After you check:

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
```

add another check to see

```
if(dt.Rows[0]["type"].ToString().Equals("A"))
```

If true, go to the admin page, else go to the user page.